# Need to parse a string, having a mask (something like this "%yr-%mh-%dy"), so i get the int values

Tags: c++, string, datetime, parsing, tags

For example i have to find time in format mentioned in the title(but `%`-tags order can be different) in a string `"The date is 2009-August-25."` How can i make the program interprete the tags and what construction is better to use for storing them among with information about how to act with certain pieces of date string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look into [`boost::date_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library. It has [IO system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) witch may be what you want but I see lack of searching.

To do custom date searching you need [`boost::xpressive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/xpressive/index.html). It contain anything you will need. Lets look into my hastily writed example. First you should parse your custom pattern, witch is easy with Xpressive. First look at header you need:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive_static.hpp>
#include <boost/xpressive/regex_actions.hpp>

//make example shorter but less clear
using namespace boost::xpressive;
```

Second define map of your special tags:

```
std::map<std::string, int > number_map;
number_map["%yr"] = 0;
number_map["%mh"] = 1;
number_map["%dy"] = 2;
number_map["%%"] = 3;  // escape a %
```

Next step is to create a regex witch will parse our pattern with tags and save values from map into variable tag_id when it find tag or save -1 otherwise:

```
int tag_id;
sregex rx=((a1=number_map)|(s1=+~as_xpr('%')))[ref(tag_id)=(a1|-1)];
```

More information and description look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.quick_start) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.symbol_tables_and_attributes).
Now lets parse some pattern:

```
  std::string pattern("%yr-%mh-%dy"); // this will be parsed

  sregex_token_iterator begin( pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), rx ), end;
  if(begin == end) throw std::runtime_error("The pattern is empty!");
```

The [`sregex_token_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.string_splitting_and_tokenization) will iterate over our tokens, and each time it will set tag_id varible. All we have to do is to build regex using this tokens. We will construct this regex using tag corresponding parts of static regex defined in array:

```
sregex regex_group[] = {
    range('1','9') >> repeat<3,3>( _d ), // 4 digit year
    as_xpr( "January" ) | "February" | "August", // not all month XD so lazy
    repeat<2,2>( range('0','9') )[    // two digit day
    check(as<int>(_) >= 1 && as<int>(_) <= 31) ], //only bettwen 1 and 31
    as_xpr( '%' )  // match escaped %
};
```

Finally, lets start build our special regex. The first match will construct first part of it. If the tag is matched and tag_id is non negative we choose regex from array, else the match is probably the delimiter and we construct regex witch match it:

```
sregex custom_regex = (tag_id>=0) ? regex_group[tag_id] : as_xpr(begin->str());
```

Next we will iterate from begin to end and append next regex:

```
while(++begin != end)
{
    if(tag_id>=0)
    {
        sregex nextregex = custom_regex >> regex_group[tag_id];
        custom_regex = nextregex;
    }
    else
    {
        sregex nextregex = custom_regex >> as_xpr(begin->str());
        custom_regex = nextregex;
    }
}
```

Now our regex is ready, lets find some dates :-]

```
std::string input = "The date is 2009-August-25.";

smatch mydate;
if( regex_search( input, mydate, custom_regex ) )
    std::cout << "Found " << mydate.str() << "." << std::endl;
```

The xpressive library is very powerful and fast. It's also beautiful use of patterns.

If you like this example, let me know in comment or points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd transform the tagged string in a regular expression with capture for the 3 fields and search for it.  The complexity of the regular expression will depend on what you want to accept for %yr.  You can also have a less strict expression and then check for valid values, this can leads to better error messages ("Invalid month: Augsut" instead of "date not found") or to false positives depending on the context.